# AppsScript search text and change color

Tags: google-apps-script

I have difficulties finding the code that says: in google slides presentation, search for all the "[Name]" and then change their color into red.

I have started out with the below three lines, any help please?

```
  var currentslides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = currentslides.getSlides();
  var gettext = slides.getText();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Presentation.getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getslides) returns an array/list of [slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide). [Slide Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide) doesn't have a `getText()` method. If you want to get the text within the slide, you can get that from the [Shape Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape) using [Slide.getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getshapes).

### Sample Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var currentslides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = currentslides.getSlides();

  //Check each slides
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    Logger.log("**slide**");
    
    //Get all shapes in the current slide
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {

      //Get text in the current shape
      var text = shape.getText();
      Logger.log(text.asString());

      //Search for the string "[Name]"
      var str = text.find("\\[Name\\]");
      str.forEach(s => {
        //Change its foreground color to red "#rrggbb"
        s.getTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#ff0000");

      });
    })
  });
  
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get all the slides within the current presentation using [Presentation.getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getslides)
2. Loop all slides, get the all the shape available in the current slide using [Slide.getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getshapes)
3. Loop all shapes, get the text per shape using [Shape.getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#gettext) which will return a [TextRange Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range)
4. Find the string `"[Name]"` in the text range using [TextRange.find(pattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#findpattern), which will return an array/list of [TextRange Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range) that match your pattern
5. Loop all text range, get its text style using [TextRange.getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#gettextstyle), which will return a [TextStyle Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style). Change its foreground color to red `"#ff0000"` using [TextStyle.setForegroundColor(foregroundColor)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setforegroundcolorforegroundcolor)

### Output:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

### Additional Reference:

- [Managing Texts on Google Slides using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/06/24/managing-texts-on-google-slides-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer